# Different behavior inside self-contained macro

Tags: macros

I'm trying to create a macro and if it contains itself, it should behave differently. If I write command like this:

```
\uw{aaa \uw{bbb} }
```

I want the result to look like this:

[image: aaa]

I got up to this command, ...

```
\newcommand{\uw}[1]{„#1“%
  \renewcommand{\uw}[1]{‚##1‘}%
}
```

... but it results into:

[image]

Can you help me to get it right pls?

Comment: You may be interested in `csquotes` and its `\enquote` macro.

Comment: What behavior do you wish in case (nested) `\uw` occurrs in moving arguments, e.g., in the title of a `\section` that gets referenced via `\nameref`/`\titleref` from within the argument of some other (nested) `\uw`-command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following suffices:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\uw}[1]{{%
  \renewcommand{\uw}[1]{‚##1‘}%
  „#1“%
}}

\begin{document}

\uw{aaa \uw{bbb} }

\end{document}
```

I've placed the redefinition inside a group *before* setting the argument.

Answer (score 11):

This defines three levels, but supports as many as you wish.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand{\uw}[1]{%
  \addtocounter{uw}{1}%
  \csname uw\romannumeral\value{uw}\endcsname{#1}%
  \addtocounter{uw}{-1}%
}
\newcounter{uw}

\newcommand{\uwi}[1]{``#1''}
\newcommand{\uwii}[1]{`#1'}
\newcommand{\uwiii}[1]{<<#1>>}

\begin{document}

\uw{abc}

\uw{abc \uw{def} ghi}

\uw{abc \uw{def \uw{ghi} lmn} pqr}

\end{document}
```

[image]